# Use get_dummies on columns with return character separated values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a data frame in which a column has values ​​as if it were a list, but separated by a return character (\n) instead of a comma. I tried to use the get_dummies function as below but without success.

Is it possible to use the get_dummies function directly? Or the need to replace the return character with a comma?

```
# import xlsx:
parques = pd.read_excel('Tabelão.xlsx')

# get_dummies:
parques = pd.get_dummies(parques, columns = ['Atividades', 'Configuração'])

# Dataframe example:
Atividades = ['esportes\nrecreação infantil\ncontemplação', 'contemplação\nrecreação infantil\nesporte', 'contemplação\nrecreação infantil', 'contemplação\nrecreação infantil\neventos culturais']
Configuração = ['relevo plano\nriacho\nlagos\nbosque\nrede de lojas', 'beria-rio\nedificações\nesplandanadas\nrede de lojas', 'bosque\nrede de caminhos\nrecantos ', 'relevo predominantemente plano\nlago\nriacho']
Nome = ['Parque Julien Rien', 'Parque da Residência', 'Feliz Lusitânia', 'Parque Barigüi']

parques = pd.DataFrame([Nome, Atividades, Configuração])

parques = parques.T

parques.columns = ['Nome', 'Atividades', 'Configuração']
```

Result: columns with all values ​​concatenated.

Comment: Use [`pd.Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), which allows you to provide a separator. Can do that separately for each column, add a prefix and then concatenate the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to clean up your data quite a bit in order to get the `get_dummies` function to work properly. The best way to use `get_dummies` is to have tidy data so that one row is one observation. In this case I have one row being either one Acitivity or one park feature the park has. So taking your example this is what I did

```
# Dataframe example:
Atividades = ['esportes\nrecreação infantil\ncontemplação', 
              'contemplação\nrecreação infantil\nesporte',
              'contemplação\nrecreação infantil', 
              'contemplação\nrecreação infantil\neventos culturais']
Configuracao = ['relevo plano\nriacho\nlagos\nbosque\nrede de lojas', 
                'beria-rio\nedificações\nesplandanadas\nrede de lojas', 
                'bosque\nrede decaminhos\nrecantos ', 
                'relevo predominantemente plano\nlago\nriacho']
Nome = ['Parque Julien Rien', 'Parque da Residência', 
        'Feliz Lusitânia','Parque Barigüi']
#splits the strings on the \n symbol to create lists of attributes for each park
Atividades = [x.split('\n') for x in Atividades]
Configuracao = [x.split('\n') for x in Configuracao]

#this tidys the data so that one row is one observation which 
#makes using get_dummies easier
list_df = []
i = 0
for name in Nome:
    for y in range(len(Atividades[i])):
        list_df.append([name, Atividades[i][y]])
    for x in range(len(Configuracao[i])):
        list_df.append([name, Configuracao[i][x]])
    i += 1
#creates the dataframe from the list of lists and then turns it into a
#dummy dataframe where the park name is the index value and a column has
#a 1 or 0 if the park has that attribute
test_df = pd.DataFrame(list_df, columns=['park_name', 'attributes'])
dummies = pd.get_dummies(test_df, columns=['attributes']).groupby(['park_name']).sum()
```

Which gives this output cleaned up as best as i can for display here:

```
               beria-rio    bosque contemplação edificações esplandanadas
park_name                   
Feliz Lusitânia         0   1   1   0   0
Parque Barigüi          0   0   1   0   0
Parque Julien Rien      0   1   1   0   0
Parque da Residência    1   0   1   1   1
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew Borlowe, but, it did not work. Even doing ctrl + c ctrl + v with the example you posted. In both cases the error is the same. I believe it is something relative to the scope of the variable since columns was declared on the penultimate row and used in the last line of code: `NameError: name 'columns' is not defined`

Comment: Updated code left out an equals sign in the last line on `columns=['attributes']` so try now just ran and it worked for me

Comment: Thank you very much Matthew Borlowe

Answer (score 0):

The items in the columns are regarded as one string, instead of list of elements. For instance, `'esportes\nrecreação infantil\ncontemplação'` is only one item, instead of a list which consists of three items.

While it is not possible to apply `.get_dummies()` directly to such a case, a relatively easier way to solve this issue -with one line of code- is to use `pd.Series.str.get_dummies()`, as ALollz suggested.

```
# Create a dictionary
data = {'Atividades' : ['esportes\nrecreação infantil\ncontemplação', 
              'contemplação\nrecreação infantil\nesporte',
              'contemplação\nrecreação infantil', 
              'contemplação\nrecreação infantil\neventos culturais'],
        'Configuracao' : ['relevo plano\nriacho\nlagos\nbosque\nrede de lojas', 
                'beria-rio\nedificações\nesplandanadas\nrede de lojas', 
                'bosque\nrede decaminhos\nrecantos ', 
                'relevo predominantemente plano\nlago\nriacho'],
        'Nome' : ['Parque Julien Rien', 'Parque da Residência', 
        'Feliz Lusitânia','Parque Barigüi']}

# Create a DataFrame
parques = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Note that there are two `.get_dummies()` methods: one is `pandas.get_dummies`, which can be applied to a DataFrame, and the other one is `pandas.Series.str.get_dummies` which can only be applied to a Series. Therefore, you need to apply the function to each column separately.

```
In []: parques['Atividades'].str.get_dummies(sep='\n')
Out[]: 
   contemplação  esporte  esportes  eventos culturais  recreação infantil
0             1        0         1                  0                   1
1             1        1         0                  0                   1
2             1        0         0                  0                   1
3             1        0         0                  1                   1
```

If you want to add a prefix as well, you may use `.add_prefix()`. (*prefix* parameter of `pandas.get_dummies` cannot be used with `pandas.Series.str.get_dummies`)

```
In []: parques['Atividades'].str.get_dummies(sep='\n').add_prefix("Atividades_")

Out[]: 
   Atividades_contemplação  Atividades_esporte  Atividades_esportes  \
0                        1                   0                    1   
1                        1                   1                    0   
2                        1                   0                    0   
3                        1                   0                    0   

   Atividades_eventos culturais  Atividades_recreação infantil  
0                             0                              1  
1                             0                              1  
2                             0                              1  
3                             1                              1
```